# how to Append defined functions to script tag of html

Tags: javascript

Hi: I want to append a js function something like function amb(){console.log("hello")} inside the script tag. But There is a problem in this. Because as the function is append to script tag it says function is not defined when i try to call. if you understand the problem or have any solution to it please help me. Thanks a lot...

```html
 <script id="append_here">
        // the appended function goes in this script
    </script>
    <script>
        a = `function amb() { console.log('hello')}`
        document.getElementById('append_here').append(a)
    </script>
    <div id="a">
        <button onclick="amb()"> amb</button>

    </div>
```

Comment: Can you describe why you want to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't append content to a script and have the browser "re-parse" the script

You can create a new script tag, add the content, and append that to the body

```html
<script>
  const a = `function amb() { console.log('hello')}`;
  const scr = document.createElement('script');
  scr.textContent = a;
  document.body.append(scr);
</script>
<div id="a">
  <button onclick="amb()"> amb </button>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot brother, I have searched for more than seven hours, and you just solved my problem in a snap of finger. May Allah help you a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval` aswell

```html
<script id="append_here">
  // the appended function goes in this script
</script>
<script>
  a = `function amb() { console.log('hello')}`;
  document.getElementById("append_here").append(eval(a));
</script>
<div id="a">
  <button onclick="amb()">amb</button>
</div>
```

Comment: of course, that simply appends the word `undefined` to that script tag ... you get the same result if you just `eval(a)` without adding the result to the script for absolutely no reason :p

Comment: Thanks a lot for your precious answer, it works too and I'm happy with the results. May Allah gives you more power to help other